# Cannot spy on Android Activity in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, mockito

I'm trying to spy on an `Activity` but it gives me the following exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "boolean org.mockito.internal.invocation.AbstractAwareMethod.isAbstract()"
at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationImpl.callRealMethod(InvocationImpl.java:109)
at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.CallsRealMethods.answer(CallsRealMethods.java:41)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:93)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:38)
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.InvocationHandlerAdapter.invoke(InvocationHandlerAdapter.java:49)
at WaitForCardActivity_Proxy.isRegisterActivated(WaitForCardActivity_Proxy.generated)
```

The code is as follows:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class WaitForCardActivityTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<WaitForCardActivity> {

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

        waitForCardActivity = spy(getActivity());
        when(waitForCardActivity.isRegisterActivated()).thenReturn(true);
    }

    ...
}
```

Activity:

```
public class WaitForCardActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public boolean isRegisterActivated() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also note: I cannot use Robolectric because I'm using `Cipher`s which give me problems when running with Robolectric.

Answer (score 0):

Spy `Activity` in following way:

```
Activity activity = spy(Activity.class);
```

**Update:**
And in your case:

```
    WaitForCardActivity activity = spy(WaitForCardActivity.class);
    when(activity.isRegisterActivated()).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(activity.isRegisterActivated());
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem. Same exception is thrown.

Comment: Please check my update. Also, I'm using `RobolectricTestRunner`, and you - `AndroidJUnit4`, but it shouldn't affect objects `spy`'ing.

Comment: One more thing: `spy`'ing `Activity` in `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` test cases is bad idea. You have to use [ActivityUnitTestCase](https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-unit-testing.html) for unit tests.

Comment: I advise you to use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org) for unit testing purposes.